# SQL Server 2005 : Syntax error near "="

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, vb.net-2010

I have this problem when I'm trying to fill my datagridview. I defined a connection to SQL Server, opened it and defined a `SqlCommand` and a reader.

The problem is when I'm trying to execute the reader with the code below it gives me the error

> Syntax error near "="

on the line that I try to execute the reader.

```
Dim sqlCommand1 As New SqlCommand("SELECT conItemName, conItemNumber, conClassName " & _
                                       "FROM Constant" & _
                                       "WHERE (Constant.conClassName = 'BoreholeType')", SesConn)
Dim tReader1 As SqlDataReader = sqlCommand1.ExecuteReader
```

Comment: This is weird, looks like valid SQL, even though round brackets are redundant. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"FROM Constant" & _
```

should be

```
"FROM Constant " & _
```

Otherwise, you have this missing space that causes the syntax error

```
... FROM ConstantWHERE (Constant.conClassName = 'BoreholeType')
```

Comment: Oh yeah, really - I did not pay attention to a missing space. Wholeheartedly +1 from me.